# How to get kivy lines to be drawn consistently

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

I'm trying to draw a simple "X" in the middle of a button. I've put in the following drawing code:

```
    width, height = self.size
    x, y = self.pos
    x1, x2 = x + int(width*0.3), x + int(width*0.7)
    y1, y2 = y + int(height*0.3), y + int(height*0.7)
    with self.canvas:
        Line(points=[x1, y1, x2, y2], width=1, cap='none')
        Line(points=[x2, y1, x1, y2], width=1, cap='none')
    self.canvas.ask_update()
```

The two diagonal lines, even though they're using the exact same integer coordinates, are not drawn the same. The upper-left to lower-right is drawn aliased, and the other is not. How can I make them consistent?

[image]

I should mention that I'm testing with the Windows version of kivy and I haven't tried it on any other platform yet.

Answer (score 1):

Add 0.5 or 0.375 to your x/y coordinates.

Comment: I tried 0.5, didn't help. Although I could try a few other combinations.

Answer (score 1):

The Line instruction with width=1.0 use GL_LINE, and then, the aliasing is done depending of the graphics card capabilities, and number of multisamplings. I've got different result with ATI and NVIDIA cards.

If you use a width != 1.0 (let's say width = 0.75), we'll build a mesh with triangles. And the result seem more consistent. Could you try?

Comment: I first noticed the problem with a width of 2, I changed it to 1 in an attempt to simplify. I didn't try anything less than 1. I won't have a chance to test it until later tonight.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized it's been well over a year and I never got back to you. Changing the width to 0.75 didn't change the blurred line at all, but it made the other one twice as thick and still full intensity.